# PWM Fan wonkiness after returning from suspend. 4.19.6-1-MANJARO

Tags: bios, multi-boot, manjaro

Edit: I am having a problem with my CPU fans. I am dual booting with windows 10, and this problem doesnt exist there. Only with linux.

When i start up the linux system, eventhing is OK. The fans run as expected. This problem begins AFTER I return from SUSPEND (sleep mode). Then the fans kick into high gear and do not leave the higher operating mode until i manually restart the computer. No debugging has removed this issue while the linux (manjaro) is in use. I had a similar problem with the same machine while running Ubuntu last summer, so I'm guessing its more of a kernel issue.

It seems as if when I return from suspend my CPU fans switch from PWM mode to DC mode. After having searched google, loud fans after suspend seem to be a common issue. Has a fix been discovered? Nothing I tried has worked so far.

pwmconfig from fancontrol doesnt generate any useful settings. Perhaps just a manual config would be my answer?

possibly relevant: this might be BIOS related since this happened to me as well when i tried to use ubuntu a year ago on this same computer. MOBO is an asus z97-e. However, this problem doesnt occur when i boot to windows 10. Any information is greatly appreciated.

Edit: the change to high speed cpu fans continues until restart.

Comment: Do the fans quiet down after a few seconds, or do they continue spinning at full speed? Most computers I'm familiar with spin their fans at full speed when they are powered on or resumed from a power-saving mode. This is normal. The fans spin down to a normal operating speed after a few seconds. So, basically, I cannot tell what your question is. Could you perhaps use the EDIT button and provide some further explanation as to what the actual problem is that you are observing, and what you expect instead?

Comment: Added an edit for you. This problem continues until i reset the computer